# Show VORA and Hive Tables

Tags: hive, hana, vora

Using HANA SDA to connect to Spark, With Vora Installed, I am looking for a way to show the Hive Tables as well as the VORA tables, It seems this should be a feature and that I am just missing how to implement this.

Is it possible for this to work, or do I need to transfer the data into VORA tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDA/Spark Controller is currently only able to either connect to Hive or to Vora since they might support different capabilities and SQL syntax. If you want to connect to both you could set up 2 Spark Controllers where one connects to Hive and one connects to Vora.

Comment: What I feared, well here's to roadmap features.